# Data Validation List Filter for Excel [Ignore rows with a 0 in a column]

Tags: excel, list, validation, filter, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of rows. Below is an example of how it could look.

| Task | Times |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 1 |

I want to create a Dropdown List in Excel that allows you to select a task that has a value in the H column > 0 (or anything aside from 0 or #VALUE / #N/A). So in the case of the above table, I want to be able to choose between Tasks B, C, or D.

What is the formula that I must in my Dropdown Data Validation List to achieve this?

Kind regards.

I tried to use OFFSET and COUNTIF, but to no avail. I wanted to count values that had a value of <> 0 in the H column, but this never worked as it gave me the whole list anyways.

For example, I tried the following

```
=OFFSET(List!$A$1,0,0,COUNTIF(A1:A100,"<>0"),1)
```

or

```
=OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$100,”<>”))
```

But it just gives me the whole list instead of Tasks B, C, and D. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which Office/Excel-Version do you have?

Comment: Latest build on Semi-Annual Update Business Channel (i.e. Office 365, Version 2208).

Comment: In the question you describe that column H is used as criterion - but in your sample formulas you are referring to column A. Please update your question and be more explicit. Propably you add some sample data of where you want to select the task and show us the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, you can't create a validation list like that via formula. Here a way to create the list on a range (paste it in a new sheet):

| Task | Times | Filtered list | Data validation list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | =IFERROR(IF(B2>0,B2,""),"") | =IF(ROWS($D$1:D2)>COUNTIF(C:C,">0")+1,"",INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C:C)/(C:C<>""),ROWS($D$1:D2)))) |
| B | 3 | =IFERROR(IF(B3>0,B3,""),"") | =IF(ROWS($D$1:D3)>COUNTIF(C:C,">0")+1,"",INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C:C)/(C:C<>""),ROWS($D$1:D3)))) |
| C | 2 | =IFERROR(IF(B4>0,B4,""),"") | =IF(ROWS($D$1:D4)>COUNTIF(C:C,">0")+1,"",INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C:C)/(C:C<>""),ROWS($D$1:D4)))) |
| D | 1 | =IFERROR(IF(B5>0,B5,""),"") | =IF(ROWS($D$1:D5)>COUNTIF(C:C,">0")+1,"",INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C:C)/(C:C<>""),ROWS($D$1:D5)))) |